# What TV movie had lost space cadets who piloted yellow tripod robots, and a squid bad guy?

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a movie I watched on TV, probably in the 90s. I think it was a made-for-TV movie.

It was about a ship with an AI. The ship was crewed by young adults. I think they were cadets?

There was an accident (like a warp drive malfunction) and they end up in another part of space where they meet a female alien whose ship had been shot down.

I remember they had manned robots they would pilot and they took them to a planet to get upgraded and they are attacked by more manned robots. They had three legs and they were yellow, I think.

I also remember the baddie had a holo-projector or something like that which allowed him to change his appearance. He commanded a massive fleet and he worked for someone he spoke to in a video chat that looked like a squid.

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember: that movie you watched on TV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That actually sounds like the Saturday-morning show [Hypernauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernauts).

> The premise of the series was that three cadets from the Academy of Galactic Exploration become lost in a Hyper Bubble (hyperspace) mid-jump and must band together with an alien named Kulai in order to survive in an unfamiliar part of the galaxy.
>
> The Hypernauts, as they name themselves, cannot match the Triiad's firepower with their own so they must rely on stealth, wits and (occasionally) their modified 'mech suits' in order to escape the Triiad. They are based in an ancient abandoned exploration ship called the Star Ranger which is hidden in an asteroid field, the Star Ranger's obsolete AI is named Horten.